# Animating StaticLayout

Tags: android, android-animation, layout-animation

For a live wallpaper project, I am using a StaticLayout on a canvas to draw some text. I intend to use alpha animation to fade out the text but all the examples I have come across on the net and on SO are for animating views.

As I do not use TextView, is there any way I can apply the animation to StaticLayout instead? Any pointers would help.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the alpha value on the paint used for the staticlayout.

Comment: That too would require a view, would it?